# latex issue while displaying equation in html page (some times it's working fine some time not ) why?

Tags: html, latex, mathquill

[latex is not working in total project and in this pages also and i included all the required script about latex](https://areavolumecalculator.com/surface-area-of-a-pyramid-5-cm-by-6-in-by-7-mm/)

```js
  <script>
      window.MathJax = {
          jax: ["input/MathML/TeX","output/HTML-CSS","output/NativeMML"],
          extensions: ["mml2jax.js","MathMenu.js","MathZoom.js","tex2math.js"],
          MathML: { extensions: ["mml3.js"]}

      };
    (function(d, script) {
          script = d.createElement('script');
          script.type = 'text/javascript';
          script.async = true;
          script.onload = function(){
              // remote script has loaded
          };
         script.src = 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/mathjax/MathJax/2.7.1/MathJax.js';
          d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
      }(document));
      if (window.MathJax === undefined ||  window.MathJax == null){
      window.MathJax =
       {
          jax: ["input/MathML","output/HTML-CSS","output/NativeMML"],
          extensions: ["mml2jax.js","MathMenu.js","MathZoom.js"],
          MathML: { extensions: ["mml3.js"]}
      };
      }
    </script>
    <script type="text/x-mathjax-config" rel="prefetch" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.7/MathJax.js ">
      MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]}});
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" async
   src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.7/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML&delayStartupUntil=configured">
</script>
```

> all the things are done at backend(using python) only.

Comment: Please add some code you've tried and paste whole error message into your question

Comment: Tq @MarekSzkudelski, i have  add some more things to existing question. please check it once